# How to prove the additive inverse of 0 is 0?

Tags: analysis, solution-verification, field-theory

Suppose you have an ordered field $(\mathbb{F}, +, \cdot, \le)$. How to prove that $-0 = 0$?

One way, I have thought so far is:

$$ -0 = -(0 + 0) = -0 + (-0)$$

and therefore since $-0 + a = a$, where $a = -0$ then $-0 = 0$, by uniqueness of additive inverse.

Is this correct?

Comment: You should know that $0+0=0$.  Now, consider your definitions.

Comment: Do you mean that therefore $0 = 0 + (-0)$, then $-0$ must also be $0$ by the definition that $a + 0 = a$ and the 0 element is unique? I'm not sure what else it could be @JMoravitz

Comment: No, start even earlier. What does $-0$ mean in the first place?

Comment: The additive inverse of $x$ answers the question "What plus $x$ becomes $0$?" The $0+0=0$ leads to the additive inverse of $0$ by answering the question "What plus $0$ becomes $0$?"

Comment: In the end, I expect you'll be able to make a correct argument.  Whether it is the shortest possible or most aesthetically pleasing to everyone shouldn't matter *that* much... though it is worth at least giving some thought to making clean arguments.

Comment: @aschepler what are you suggesting? I think what I said is the same as the current top answer

Comment: That the additive inverse is unique is a simple theorem. That $-(a+b) = (-a) + (-b)$ is a simple theorem. Neither of these is actually necessary, and it's easy to prove directly from the field axioms.

Comment: (My first comment was to clarify what I believed @JMoravitz was hinting with their first comment; not necessarily that it's the only way to do it.)

Comment: I do not quite see the field axioms way. Could you elaborate? If you mean like the first answer, I don't get the second step.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have $0=0+(-0)=-0$. The first equality is by definition of the additive inverse, and the second equality is by definition of the additive identity (zero).

Comment: Do you mean basically what I said in the comments originally is correct?

Comment: @user129393192 My solution does not use uniqueness.

Comment: Then could you please explain the second equality in more detail?

Comment: @user129393192 The element "$0$" is defined to be the additive identity, i.e. it satisfies the property that $0+x = x$ for any $x$. Then, just replace $x$ by $-0$.

Comment: Thanks. This makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the comments, one way to see this is to start from $0+0=0 \; \; (\text{eq.} \; 1)$. Then, the axiom of additive inverses gives that $0-0=0 \; \; (\text{eq.} \; 2)$. Setting $(\text{eq.} \; 1)=(\text{eq.} \; 2)$ gives $0+0=0-0$, and we obtain $0=-0$ since $0$ is the additive identity.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

> therefore since $-0 +a = a$, where $a = -0$ then $-0 = 0$, by uniqueness of additive inverse.

This doesn't work because the meaning of "additive inverse" is always of the form $a + (-a) = 0$ and/or $(-a) + a = 0$. Your $(-0) + (-0) = -0$ doesn't match that since the right side is not obviously $0$ (without the result we're currently to prove).

If you've already proved that for any $a$, there is only one $z$ such that $a + z = a$, then you could fix this by referencing that instead of saying "by uniqueness of additive inverse".

Or, the other answers present a different (maybe "simpler") approach: $0 + (-0) = 0$ by the definition of additive inverse. (That is, substitute $a=0$ into $a + (-a) = 0$.) And $0 + (-0) = -0$ because $0$ (appearing at the left) is the additive identity. Therefore $-0 = 0$.

Comment: I'm saying that let $a = -0$, not that $-0$ is $0$. You see $-0 + (-0) = -0$, which is of form $-0 + a = a$, so $-0$ must be additive inverse.

Comment: That's an equation for additive identity, not additive inverse. And then you need a previous result or proof that if $z+a=a$, then $z=0$.